# Node module to execute tasks grunt : "Gruntfile.js" not find

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, gruntjs

I'm currently trying to develop a module that will allow node to run Grunt tasks from the command line. This Node module is installed globally :

```
C:\Users\pcharpin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\task-app
```

The goal is that the use of "Grunt" commands is transparent to the user. To better explain my approach, a simple example of the use of my node module:

```
C:\Users\pcharpin\Desktop\demo-app> task-app copy
```

In this example, my module will copy a source directory to a destination directory.

Unfortunately, when I run the task Grunt, my node module indicates to me that there is no file "Gruntfile.js" within the directory "demo-app". However, this file should be found by my Node module within its own directory.

My tree Node module:

- Task app
- node_modules

  - grunt
- src

  - task-app.js
- Gruntfile.js
- package.json
- README.md
- ...

My task-app.js file, here's the code:

```
#!/Usr/bin/env node

var grunt = require('grunt');

var args = process.argv.splice(2)

checkArguments(args);

checkArguments function(args) {
    [...]
    runCopy();
}

runCopy = function() {
   var spawn = require('child_process') spawn.
   var exec = spawn('cmd', ['/ c', 'grunt copy']);
   exec.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
     console.log('' + data);
   });
   exec.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
     console.log('' + data);
   });
}
```

Then in my "Gruntfile.js" file, I have the code to perform the copy of the source to the destination directory:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

   grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    copy {
     srcWeb {
      files: [{
        cwd: '<%= pkg.srcWeb%>', //root to copy
        src: '**/*', // copy all files and subfolders
        dest: '<%= pkg.name%>/www/', // destination folder
        expand: true // When required using cwd
     }]
   }
 }
});
```

I don't understand why the Node module is not found in the "Gruntfile.js" file.

Is it required to have a file "Gruntfile.js" in this project directory? Is there another solution?

I would like to know too, is it possible that the file "Gruntfile.js" can read the file "package.json" in the project directory? This is to allow the user to configure this file to change the source path for example.

**EDIT :**

After some researches, I'm getting closer to the solution to my problem. To change the execution of "Gruntfile.js" which is the current directory by default, we can use --gruntfile option in command line.

As indicated in the source code grunt (grunt/lib/grunt/tasks.js) :

```
//Get any local Gruntfile or tasks that might exist. Use --gruntfile   override
//if specified, otherwise search the current directory or any parent.
```

How can I specify the path of "Gruntfile.js" (found in my node module installed globally) for any Windows user ?

Here's an example :

C:\Users\username\projects\demo-app> task-app copy

In my source code, I execute the grunt task like this with --gruntfile option :

```
runCopy = function() {
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  var pathGruntfile = 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module\task-app';
  var exec = spawn('cmd', ['/ c', 'grunt --gruntfile' + pathGruntfile + ' Gruntfile.js']);
  exec.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log('' + data);
  });
  exec.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('' + data);
 });
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

Pending a response, I found a temporary solution to get the "Gruntfiles.js" inside my Node module. But the disadvantage is to install all Node modules dependancies and my Node Module locally in the current directory.

```
var pathDirCurrent = process.cwd();
var pathGruntfile = pathDirCurrent.concat('\\node_modules\\task-app\\Gruntfile.js');    
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var exec = spawn('cmd', ['/c', 'grunt --gruntfile ' + pathGruntfile + ' create']);
exec.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log('' + data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I understand the logic of using Grunt tasks. When you have a web project application which need to use tasks grunt, it must have the Gruntfile.js in current directory.

However, like as I said from my "edit 2", we can specified the Gruntfile.js with ---gruntfile option. So, it's not a disadvantage cause Grunt tool works with the Gruntfile.js in current directory where there is your web project application.

For each task grunt, I use the --gruntfile option to specify the path of Gruntfile.js as my example from "edit 2".

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running grunt from?

Your projects structure and grunt file looks OK. Maybe try and include a base task:

```
 grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy']);
```

Comment: I'm running grunt from my node module installed globally. 

I forgot to explain that the "grunt module" is included inside "node_modules" from my node module "task-app".

Comment: does this work when you run grunt from the correct folder (same level as GruntFile.js)? My guess is even tho your grunt is global, it does not know which "grunt" to run. c:\myapp\ --> \grunt

Comment: Yes, when I'm running grunt from the folder where is Gruntfile.js (node module task-app directory), it's work. But, I tried to running grunt from my project directory, it's not working. 

However, I installed local grunt from my project directory and I have the same message : Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile.

The only solution is to have this Gruntfile.js in project directory ?